# difference between deleting a node_module folder and running npm uninstall <package_name>

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

Is there any difference between just deleting a package directly from the node_modules folder and running npm uninstall  since npm just deletes the package anyway?

Comment: `npm` does way more than delete the directory. It does non trivial things that you will not want to do yourself. Have a look https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/uninstall.js

Comment: this explains it all

Answer (score 1):

If you delete npm_modules everything will be install the same all dependencies and stuff because the package-lock is the one having the reference of your dependencies and the versions of them. you’ll need to remove the dependency manually at your package.json but now you’re going to get some conflicts because  your package and package-lock now mismatch. If that happens you need to delete your package-lock and create a new one by npm install. And as this dependencies change quite often you run the risck of having a break change on a new version or a bunch of deprecated warnings. To kind of prevent that you can add an .npmrc file with save-exact=true.
Or you can just run npm uninstall and this command will remove the dependency from node_modules, package-lock and package

I was writing this on a cellphone. Sorry for not making it pretty :3 ‍♀️

Comment: I noticed after removing a package ```npm``` also audits other packages

Comment: I also only remembered ```package.json``` manages the dependencies between various packages after you mentioned it. Nice explanation there

Answer (score 1):

If any folder is deleted directly from node_modules , the particular folder will be downloaded again when npm install or npm update command is run for the next time .

**npm uninstall will remove the folder from node modules as well as remove dependency from package.json** . So it will not get downloaded automatically when npm install or npm update command is run for the next time .